# Cocos2D-JS game draw charts using external lib?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, highcharts, cocos2d-iphone

I've just played with Cocos2D-JS a few days, still a chicken :D. I'm not sure if we can integrate external JS/HTML5 libs for drawing charts(line chart, bar chart, etc,...)? I've had a quick check on SDKBOX, but seems there's no help on drawing chart in Cocos2D-JS game. Please kindly help me.

Comment: It probably may not answer your question, but hey, you are not the only one, see [this question](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-pass-externs-file-like-underscore-js-when-using-m-web-advanced/23161/3) - have you tried that solution?

Comment: Thanks Pawel Fus, I didn't have a chance to look at it. Btw, I've also changed to use Unity, anyway, thanks again